# How to apply function for all Collection

Tags: node.js, meteor, collections

I want to update my collection in `server.js` by using a function.
When I change one field I need to change multiple collections.
My question is how can I use a parameter as a Collection name. Is there any way for it or I must write a function for each Collection?

```
update: function(personID,option) {
  return Personel.update(
    { id: personID },
    { $set: option },
    { multi: true }
  );
},
```

I want to apply this logic for separate collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trickier workaround for this problem. you need to actually bind all of your collection in a single object.

```
CollectionList = {};

CollectionList.Personel = new Mongo.Collection('personel');
CollectionList.secondCollection = new Mongo.Collection('second');
```

after that you pass as your collection name as a string into the method.

```
update: function(collectionName,personID,option){
     return CollectionList[collectionName].update(
             //..rest of your code
            );
```

Comment: On the client you can find collections under `this.global` or `window.global`, i.e. `this.global['Personel']` refers to the `Personel` collection. This avoids the need to create your own object.

Comment: thanks again @MichelFloyd . There is always something new to learn from you. I didn't know about it before.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
var Personel = new Mongo.Collection('personel');
var Items = new Mongo.Collection('items');
var SomeOtherCollection = new Mongo.Collection('someOtherCollection');

....

update: function(personID, option, collectionName) {
  // Choose collection by given name
  var Collection = {
    Personel: Personel,
    Items: Items,
    SomeOtherCollection: SomeOtherCollection
  }[collectionName];

  return Collection.update(
    { id: personID },
    { $set: option },
    { multi: true }
  );
},
```